# How to create a dashed line that alternates between two colours?

Tags: java, awt, jfreechart

I'm using JFreeChart and want to plot a series of data using a line that alternates between gray and black dashes, with no space between. i.e. grayblackgrayblackgrayblack

JFreeChart will only accept an AWT Stroke or Shape object as the method of rendering series.

As I understand it, a BasicStroke can only have one colour and alternate between opaque and transparent. Is there another class that implements Stroke that would allow multiple colours? Or is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar issue with JFreeChart. I ended up simply extending the appropriate plot and overriding some of the draw methods. It's not an ideal solution but there is simply a limit on what you can do with JFreeChart.

Comment: I'd consider it a last resort, but perfectly doable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to risk being shot down in flames here because I'm an Android programmer without specific experience of AWT or JFreeChart, but I'll have a go.

Can you create your dashed line that alternates between two colours by superimposing two dashed lines, and offsetting the dash phase of one of them so that the dashes mesh together? I just looked at AWT's `BasicStroke` class and I see that as well as specifying a dash array, you can specify the dash 'phase' as well.

Here's a potentially useful URL that shows how setting the phase affects the dashed stroke (near the bottom of the page): http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jfc/ch04_05.htm

Comment: It's a great idea Trevor, but unfortunately will not work in this context. The chart renderer will only accept a single object as a parameter, so without overriding the chart rendering methods it can't be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You might try a cyclic [`LinearGradientPaint`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/LinearGradientPaint.html) in conjunction with your [`BasicStroke`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BasicStroke.html).

Addendum: To render sharp edges, consider [java.awt.TexturePaint](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/TexturePaint.html). To render orthogonal bondaries, consider [java.awt.geom.Path2D](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html).

Comment: As I understand it, LinearGradientPaint always paints a gradual shift from the first colour to the second. Is there any way to make the gradient size zero (so that the colour change is immediate), but delay the cycle so that the dashes are of a certain length?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it without overriding any `paint()` or `paintComponent()` methods. Essentially what you do is make two rectangles with `drawRect()`, using two different kinds of strokes, one with the stroke's phase property slightly higher than the other, and two different colors. Here it is:

```
g.setColor(Color.black);
g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0, new float[]{5, 5}, 0));
g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        
g.setColor(Color.white);
g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0, new float[]{5, 5}, 5));
g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

The very last variable of the `BasicStroke`'s constructor is the phase, which is what you're looking for.